# AngularDart : Property binding ngIf not used by any directive on an embedded template error while using *ngIf

Tags: dart, angular-dart, dart-html, angular-ng-if

I am using AngularDart where i need to show and hide component based on boolean value **registerDisplay**. Tried using ***ngIf** , but throwing an error . Below is the html.

**app_component.html:**

```
<div *ngIf="!registerDisplay">
    <register-component></register-component>
</div>
```

[image]

What might be the reason. I came across solution for the error in Angular typescript . But that is not applicable to dart. Please suggest .

Answer (score 3):

You need to register directives you want to use in the template

```
@Component(
  selector: 'my-component',
  directives: const [
    MaterialButtonComponent,
    MaterialIconComponent,
    MaterialTooltipDirective,
    ...
    NgIf,
    ...
  ],
```

instead of registering every directive individually you can register
the common set provided by Angular itself by adding

```
coreDirectives,
```

to the `directives` list.

See also https://github.com/dart-lang/angular/blob/master/angular/lib/src/common/common_directives.dart

Comment: Glad to hear. If this solves your problem, consider accepting the answer (using the check mark below the up/down-vote buttons)